# Indirect Addressing of Function Variables

Tags: c

- IDE: MPLAB IDE 8.87
- Language: C
- Compilers: C30/ASM30
- Debugger/Programmer: MPLAB ICD 3
- uController: Pic24F

Hi,

I have a function Temp_Picture. Function Temp_Picture has variable declarations as follows:

```
void Temp_Picture(void) 
{   
    unsigned char Year_T  = count_tens(Year);
    unsigned char Year_U  = count_ones(Year,Year_T);            
    unsigned char Day_T   = count_tens(Day);
    unsigned char Day_U   = count_ones(Day,Day_T);
    unsigned char Hours_T = count_tens(Hours);
    unsigned char Hours_U = count_ones(Hours,Hours_T);
    unsigned char Month_T = count_tens(Month);
    unsigned char Month_U = count_ones(Month,Month_T);
    unsigned char Minute_T= count_tens(Minute);
    unsigned char Minute_U= count_ones(Minute,Minute_T);
    function_b(Non void);

}
```

I want function_b to indirectly access the variables in Temp_Picture.

Since the variables are being created into the stack each time this function is called the variables addresses are effectively unknown however there is a pattern:

[image: xxx]

All of the variables are stacked together, and I want to take advantage of this situation, but I am not sure if this will work in all scenarios.

**Do you think there is a problem with this and if so what is the best approach**

Comment: can some one please add the following picture at the location xxx http://i.stack.imgur.com/LbDSk.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *may* be a pattern. However, you shouldn't rely on this.

The C standard does not specify how the stack is arranged. Code that makes assumptions about the stack is very brittle. Changing compiler, or adding flags that may affect the stack (e.g., `-O3`) will break stuff.

Packing all related fields into a struct is the way to go:

```
struct {
    unsigned char Year_T;
    unsigned char Year_U;
    unsigned char Day_T;
    unsigned char Day_U;
    unsigned char Hours_T;
    unsigned char Hours_U;
    unsigned char Month_T;
    unsigned char Month_U;
    unsigned char Minute_T;
    unsigned char Minute_U;
} some_struct;
```

Then you just have to pass a reference to the struct:

```
function_b(&your_struct);
```

It's important to note that `your_struct` will only exist until `Temp_Picture` returns.

Comment: I agree with you, but what now that he's done this? So he has a struct living on the stack that has the same temporary-address problem he had before.

Comment: @SanJacinto @Bathseba I didn't mean to say the layout of a `struct` is reliable. I hope my edit clarifies that. Thanks for commenting, cheers

Comment: @MBlanc, Thanks for clarifying, +1 and cleaner than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work since you cannot guarantee that the variables are added to the stack in *contiguous* memory. (You can only guarantee that for elements of array types).

In fact to assume this is *undefined behaviour*.

Using an array `unsigned char[]` guarantees contiguity in memory so your function is then well-defined.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Bathsheba this helped, and I see why both this and the struct options solve the problem, I picked the struct answer simply because I think it increases readability and organization where as the array method requires additional information to understand whats where